# Best technique for "expiring" a shopping cart after a certain amount of time? (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a simple custom shopping cart (yes, reinventing the wheel) in Rails. The cart must function similarly to fab.com's in that the users may only hold items in their cart for up to 12 minutes. Adding anything to the cart restarts the timer, but when the time is up the cart is emptied.

I currently have the front-end aspects of this code working (using a simple jQuery timer plugin) as well as an expiration timestamp on the cart that is set properly every time an item is added. **My question is: what is the best technique for emptying the user's cart after the time is up? EDIT For clarity: I'm talking about a server-side solution as the client-side aspects of this are working fine.** I've thought about some kind of delayed job / resque task but that seems overly complicated. I guess the right solution might be some kind of callback on the cart model that checks the expiration date every time anything is updated?

Some relevant code snippets below.

Cart Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_items
  has_many :products, :through => :cart_items

  def <<(cart_item)
    # add a cart_item to the cart, avoiding redundancy
    existing_cart_item = self.cart_items.select{ |ci| ci.product_id == cart_item.product_id }
    if existing_cart_item.size > 0
      existing_cart_item.first.quantity += cart_item.quantity
      existing_cart_item.first.save
    else
      self.cart_items << cart_item
    end
  end

  def reset_expiry(seconds)
    self.expires_at = Time.now + seconds
  end

end
```

Cart Items Controller

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @cart_item = CartItem.new(params[:cart_item])
    @cart_item.unit_price = @cart_item.product.price
    current_cart << @cart_item
    current_cart.reset_expiry 720
    current_cart.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:notice] = "Added #{@cart_item.product.name} to cart."
        redirect_to current_cart
      end
      format.json do
        render :json => {
          :time => 720,
          :count => current_cart.total_quantity,
          :data => render_to_string(:partial => 'layouts/menu_cart_item.html.erb', :collection => current_cart.cart_items, :as => :item)
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution! It seems I answered my own question with that last comment. Thanks @Catcall for the ideas.

In the end the answer was very simple. I added a line to my `current_cart` method in my `application_controller`:

```
  def current_cart  
    if user_signed_in?
      if session[:cart_id]  
        @current_cart ||= current_user.carts.find(session[:cart_id])
        if @current_cart.purchased_at || @current_cart.expired?
          session[:cart_id] = nil
        end
      end  
      if session[:cart_id].nil?  
        @current_cart = current_user.carts.create!  
        session[:cart_id] ||= @current_cart.id  
      end
    end
    @current_cart  
  end
```

And added a couple convenience methods to the `cart.rb` model:

```
  def seconds_left
    if self.expires_at
      return (self.expires_at - Time.now).round
    else
      -1
    end
  end

  def expired?
    if self.expires_at
      return (self.expires_at < Time.now)
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

and a few methods on product.rb so that i can get accurate up-to-the-moment quantities for each item:

```
  def remaining
    # starting inventory minus the total quantity of all
    # cart items in carts which haven't expired yet or have been purchased
    inventory - (cart_items.includes(:cart).where('carts.expires_at > ? OR carts.purchased_at IS NOT NULL',Time.now).to_a.sum(&:quantity))
  end

  def on_hold
    cart_items.includes(:cart).where('carts.expires_at > ? AND carts.purchased_at IS NULL',Time.now).to_a.sum(&:quantity)
  end

  def purchased
    cart_items.includes(:cart).where('carts.purchased_at IS NOT NULL',Time.now).to_a.sum(&:quantity)
  end

  def on_hold?
    (remaining < 1 && on_hold > 0)
  end

  def sold_out?
    (remaining < 1 && on_hold < 1)
  end
```

Now a new cart is simply created for the user if their current one has expired! Nice and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Since users can close their browser, I think you'll have to do this on the server side. You might be able to do it more efficiently from the client side, but you still have to account for closed browsers. IMO, you can make a good case for doing both, although that introduces some maintenance issues.

You might try updating a cart timeout value in your database whenever there's a change to the cart.  Then use a server-side, timed procedure that either moves or deletes items from expired carts, and then updates (or deletes) the timeout.

The timed procedure itself might be as simple as a single SQL statement. I would probably start with something like this, written as a stored procedure.

```
DELETE FROM carts 
WHERE cart_expiry_ts < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

You'll have to check your target platform's docs to find out exactly what you need to do to write a working stored procedure. In PostgreSQL I'd start with something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expire_carts()
  RETURNS void AS 
    'DELETE FROM carts 
     WHERE cart_expiry_ts < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;'
LANGUAGE SQL
```

And I'd run that by executing this statement.

```
SELECT expire_carts();
```

Some dbms platforms include their own agents for running jobs on a timer.  Some don't. On the platforms that don't, use the system utility. That's usually cron on Unix variants, and "Scheduled tasks" under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I need to update the question for more clarity. __1)__ The cart is already clearing just fine "from the client side", but as you pointed out this is not a solution but rather just part of the UI. My question is regarding the server side logic only. __2)__ As I mentioned, I am already setting a timeout value on the cart whenever there is a change. Its the "timed procedure" that I would like advice on.

Comment: are you suggesting that i create a cron job every time a visitor adds something to their cart? doesn't feel like the right approach! i'm thinking the right solution is going to involve verifying the cart expiration whenever its read - like in an `after_find` callback perhaps...

Comment: No, you just need a single cron job that runs every minute or every two minutes.

Comment: Even with a cron job running every minute, some errant orders could slip through on very high-traffic sales. Adding cron to the mix also increases maintenance cost. I think tackling the issue from the other end (when the cart is read) is going to work best.

Comment: "some errant orders could slip through on very high-traffic sales" Perhaps. If your platform is saturated, as it might be in high-traffic sales or in a DDOS attack, all server-side code is questionable.  (But serializable database transactions are still serializable, and they're still transactions.) If the user closes the browser, does your Rails code still execute and expire the user's cart, or does the cart get orphaned?

Comment: database transactions are reversible, yes, but i'd rather avoid having to explain that to customers ;). the beauty of the solution above is that there isn't any code to execute in order to expire/clear carts. if the customer bounces, the cart_item isn't counted against the inventory after the expiration date. i'll include the other methods i added in my answer above to further explain